# Windows: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

Tags: windows, mongodb

Here I am installing Mongodb for first time on Windows 8.1 through .msi file downloaded from https://www.mongodb.com and getting following error.

```
mongod.exe - Application Error
---------------------------
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application. 
---------------------------
```

How this error can be removed?
As per R&D, I found that its issue with some windows dependencies

Answer (score 2):

please keep libeay32.dll and  ssleay32.dll  inside folder where mongodump.exe is present.

Comment: This was it!  of course an obvious reminder: the mongodump and restore versions have version specific libeay32 and ssleay32 dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this issue. It's not problem related to mongodb or any other application software but missing following packages in window itself. Install these packages and it will work fine.

Microsoft visual c++ packages

1. microsoft visual c++ 2005 redistributable
2. microsoft visual c++ 2005 redistributable x64
3. microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable x64 9.0.3
4. microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable x86 9.0.3
5. microsoft visual c++ 2012 redistributable x86 11.0.6
6. microsoft visual c++ 2012 redistributable x64 11.0.6
7. microsoft visual c++ 2013 redistributable x64 12.0
8. microsoft visual c++ 2013 redistributable x86 12.0